# Where can I get free apparmor profiles?

Tags: security

Apparmor profiles: Security tight paranoic hardened very secure hard to hack, %100 bullet proof (last one a joke lol)

Maybe a link.

Comment: Are you looking for AppArmor profiles for specific applications, or just a general database?

Comment: @Alex while we know what you are trying to ask from the title, can you make the question content a bit clearer and more useful to future users? I would edit, but I don't want to make it say something you are not asking.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to ubuntu forums, this are my first posts, and my native language is not english. I just wanted some free apparmor profiles. But some one already answer my question. The aplication I want to use with apparmor is vmware player. Thanks guys

Answer (score 3):

[This wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/AppArmorProfiles) provides information about AppArmor profiles that are present by default or can be installed through the package manager. You may be surprised how many are available, including those that are not in use by default. I recommend reading that before seeking profiles elsewhere.

AppArmor profiles for Ubuntu that are still in development are not generally present by default or available by installing a package, however. You can find them in [this Bazaar repository](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~apparmor-dev/apparmor-profiles/master/files).